# Blank JPanel after adding a JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jtextfield

Working on adding a GUI to my simple craps simulation program.

Made a new JPanel and added a few JTextFields to it with a default text value. I get no error, and the code runs, but all I get is a blank window with nothing in it.

Here is the code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class CrapsGUI extends JFrame
{
   JPanel jp = new JPanel();
   JLabel jl = new JLabel();
   JTextField die1 = new JTextField("Die 1",30);
   JTextField die2 = new JTextField("Die 2",30);
   JTextField sum = new JTextField("Sum",30);
   JTextField point = new JTextField("Point",30);
   JTextField status = new JTextField("Status",30);

   public CrapsGUI()
   {
      setTitle("Craps Simulator 2013");
      setVisible(true);
      setSize(400, 200);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      jp.add(die1);
      jp.add(die2);
      jp.add(sum);
      jp.add(point);
      jp.add(status);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Craps craps = new Craps();

      CrapsGUI crapsGUI = new CrapsGUI();
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't added the `JPanel` that contains the visible components.

```
add(jp);
```

Comment: Wow can't believe I missed that obvious one. All works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Three things come to mind

1. Make sure you are starting your UI's from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  See [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html) for more details
2. Call `setVisible` only after you have finished creating your UI
3. It would also be helpful if you added something to you frame.  Try using `add(jp)`

Answer (score 0):

```
try this one:

public static void createAndShowGUI() {
    // Create and set up the window.
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Sample Frame");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    // first text box
    JPanel textbox1Panel = new JPanel();
    textbox1Panel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(textbox1Panel, 0));
    textbox1Panel.setOpaque(true);
    textbox1Panel.setBackground(new Color(100, 0, 131));
    textbox1Panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));
    textbox1Panel.add(die1);
    textbox1Panel.add(die2);
    textbox1Panel.add(sum);
    textbox1Panel.add(point);

    // Set the menu bar and add the label to the content pane.

    frame.getContentPane().add(textbox1Panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

    // Display the window.
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```